# 100% background tile, in 100% height divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am having an issue with a layout I am trying to develop.
I basically have split the view-port into 2 equal width divs with a different background tiled image in each.

I have it stretching full screen 100%, but have a problem on scrolling.

The background image is cropped to the original height of the view-port..!

Here's the html:

```
<body>

<div id="container">

        <div id="left" class="half">
        left content here
        </div>

        <div id="right" class="half">
            right content here
        </div>
</div>

</body>
```

Here's the css:

```
html, body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height:100%;
    font: 14px Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, Geneva, sans-serif;
    color: #505050;
}

div#container {
    height: 100%;
    min-width: 800px;
    min-height: 500px;
}

div.half {
    height: 100%;
    width: 50%;
}

div.half#left {
    float: left;
    text-shadow: 0px 1px 1px white;
    background-image: url(images/metalBG.jpg);
}

div.half#right {
    float: right;
    text-shadow: 0px -1px 1px black;
    background-image: url(images/fabricBG.jpg);
}
```

I'm wondering if the is maybe a javascript, hence included in this cat also.

Comment: If I recall, using 100% height under the body will render the div as the height of the browser window size. Since it doesn't go beneath the fold, when you scroll, the image will stop at 100% the height of the window. I'm on my way out so I don't have enough time to give a full answer, but this might help you on your quest.

Comment: Yes on closer inspection, that does look like whats happening.

Comment: So is there any way, to have the left and right divs keep there 100% height upon scrolling. My guess is this would involve javascript.

Comment: if the html will keep 100% on scroll, perhaps i could make the body absolute, and the presiding divs absolute also.

Answer (score 0):

I would use Firebug or similar to verify that it's a background problem, not a DIV sizing problem. Maybe what's clipped is not your BG image, but rather the height of your DIVs.

If this is not the case, you can try adding

```
background-repeat:repeat,
```

to your CSS for `div.half`, but this is already the default value, so unless you have some CSS somewhere overriding it, should be in place anyway.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to get me the result i want, not tested in explorer yet though.

```
html {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    font: 14px Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, Geneva, sans-serif;
    color: #505050;
    background-image: url(images/metalBG.jpg);
}

body {
    float:right;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    width:50%;
    background-image: url(images/fabricBG.jpg);
}

#left {
    float:left;
    margin-left:-600px;
    width:550px;
}
```

Comment: changing the width and position of the body is an interesting approach I haven't seen before :) Just be careful about the window size; given that your margin looks like its using pixels (though that could be what you're looking for)?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't run this code but adding it to the existing code *should* work (I hope :P).
You can keep the divs and their backgrounds fixed where they are using something like:

```
 .half{
    position:fixed; /* keeps the divs in the same place */
    overflow:auto;  /* overflowing content will scroll */
    background-attachment:fixed; /* the background won't scroll with content */
 }
```